# efficient way of counting occurence

Tags: c

I have to count how many times "array[val.a][val.b][val.c][val.d]"  was called. For ex array[0][1][2][1] was called one time from some other function. I am doing it by using a 4d array and I am 
able to get the correct results. Is there a efficient way of doing it?

```
typedef struct
{
    int a; // value of  0<=a<10 
    int b; // 0<=b<10
    int c; // 0<=c<5
    int d; //0<=d<3
}addr;

int array[10][10][5][3];  // memory used = 10*10*5*3*4bytes= 6Kbytes
// Is there a way I do not have to use the array .


void countOccurences(addr val)
{

   array[val.a][val.b][val.c][val.d]++; //giving me correct results.

}
```

Comment: What does _how many times a variable was called_ mean?

Comment: Please clarify what "efficient" means in Your case (fast, compact, ...). Should it be portable (hardware, compiler)? What restrictions You have (regarding use of libraries, tools)?

Answer (score 1):

Efficient? In time or memory?
How you are doing it is very efficient in time. Bad for memory.
But it's not *that* bad.

6kB is nothing. Unless your programming an ic or something :P. Anyhow, your program must be a lot bigger than 6kB so this ought to be negligable.